# Fail shell script at npm install if there are high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: bash, shell, npm

I want to fail the packaging script for my application if the npm install shows vulnerabilities with high severity.

Example:

```
added 137 packages from 151 contributors and audited 4041 packages in 8.689s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

**What I have now**
I'm doing it with grep, but this does not sound like a good solution because minor output adjustments of the audit can break it without finding it out immediately.

```
function npm-prod-install-audit() {
    if npm install --no-optional --only=prod | grep "high severity";then
        echo "Audit failed!  Please update your packages."
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Audit passed ✅";
    fi
}
```

Is there any proper solution on this?

Comment: As the error message suggests, [npm audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities) looks like the proper way to check vulnerabilities before installing.

Comment: it possible/likey that errors/warnings are output from `npm` via the std-err. Just test if that is true from the cmd line `npm install --no-.... 2> /tmp/nmp.errs; ls -l /tmp/nmp.errs` . If the file has a non-zero size, then cat `/tmp/nmp.errs` to see the text generated. BUT you may see the error messages appear on the terminal screen, which means the error msgs are written to std-out, so they should be processed by the `| grep ...` without issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `npm audit` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit. It will exit with non-zero return code if there are vulnerabilities found. You can control on which level you want to fail by using `--audit-level=(low|moderate|high|critical)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this if you are trying to fail the build and force the engineers to fix the bugs.

Add the following as part of your `scripts` section in `package.json` file

```
"audit:high_and_critical": "audit_high_and_critical() { cmd=\" yarn audit \" /bin/bash -c 'command $cmd || exit_code=\"$?\" && ((\"$exit_code\" >= \"${LEVEL:=8}\")) && exit 1 || exit 0'; }; audit_high_and_critical"
```